# Oracle Error: ORA-06512: at "ADMIN.CHECKTABLEEXIST", line 17

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create stored procedure where I'm checking to see if a table exist or not and then drop otherwise recreate.

```
create or replace procedure Checktableexist
    (p_tab_name in all_tables.table_name%type)
    authid definer
is
    n pls_integer;
begin

    SELECT count(*) into n FROM all_tables where table_name = p_tab_name;


    if n = 1
    then
        -- no need to specify schema because it's the procedure owner
        execute immediate 'drop table '|| p_tab_name;
    end if;

    execute immediate 'create table p_tab_name as select * from xvz WHERE 1=0';

end Checktableexist;
/
```

exec Checktableexist('abc1')

I'm getting the error below:

```
BEGIN Checktableexist('abc1'); END;
Error at line 1
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
ORA-06512: at "ADMIN.CHECKTABLEEXIST", line 17
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: Why are you bothering to check if it exists.  Just execute the `DROP`.

Comment: Your `create table` statement always creates a table named literally `P_TAB_NAME`.  I assume that you really want to do the same string concatenation that you're doing to build the `DROP .TABLE` statement.  That said, I'm hard-pressed to understand why you'd want to create a new table that has the same structure as an existing table and why you'd be doing that often enough (and apparently in enough schemas) to justify creating such a procedure in the first place

Comment: Justin @ suppose I'm doing like this 'create table ' || p_tab_name || 'as select * from PS_RX_STG WHERE 1=0' thereafter I'm getting same error

Comment: Your dynamic SQL in this block is only concerned with the owner's tables.  I really think you need to change `all_tables` to `user_tables`.  Also your condition for dropping is more coherent (with `all_tables`, you could see scenarios n >1 at times).

Comment: Patrick @ thanks for your reply same error.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a table `p_tab_name` instead of using it as a variable. Take it out of the string literal, and you should be OK:

```
execute immediate 
'create table ' || p_tab_name || ' as select * from xvz WHERE 1=0';
```

Comment: thanks for your reply same I do but I'm getting same error.